# Setting Child CascadingDropDown Asynchronously in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajaxcontroltoolkit, cascadingdropdown

I have 3 CascadingDropDowns and am trying to set their values from the clientside. I have a solution that works, but uses setTimeout which is not always reliable, so I am looking for a more stable solution.

The problem I'm having is that after setting the Parent CascadingDropDown, its child is not immediately populated -- it takes some milliseconds to load the data. Therefore in the javascript code if I assign the parent dropdown a value and then try to loop through the corresponding child values to find the value I want, the child dropdown will not be immediately populated since its data has not come back from the web service.

Here is the code using timeouts that is working for me -- but I want to get away from the timeouts.

```
for (i = 0; i < ddlPC1.length; i++) {
        if (ddlPC1.options[i].value == test1) {
            var ajaxcdd_ddlPC2 = $find(document.getElementById('ajaxcdd_ddlPC2ID').value);
            ddlPC1.selectedIndex = i;
            ajaxcdd_ddlPC2._onParentChange(null, false);
            break;
        }
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        var ddlPC2 = document.getElementById(document.getElementById('ddlPC2ID').value);
        for (i = 0; i < ddlPC2.length; i++) {
            if (ddlPC2.options[i].value == test2) {
                ddlPC2.selectedIndex = i;
                var ajaxcdd_ddlPC3 = $find(document.getElementById('ajaxcdd_ddlPC3ID').value);
                ajaxcdd_ddlPC3._onParentChange(null, false);
                break;
            }
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            var ddlPC3 = document.getElementById(document.getElementById('ddlPC3ID').value);
            for (i = 0; i < ddlPC3.length; i++) {
                if (ddlPC3.options[i].value == test3) {
                    ddlPC3.selectedIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, 250);
    }, 250);
```

test1, test2, and test3 are the values that I want to assign the dropdowns to. If I remove the timeouts, the for loops will not iterate since there is not any data immediately populated in the child drop downs (data coming from webservice, and takes about 100 ms).

Is there a way to set the child drop downs (ddlPC2, ddlPC3) without having to use setTimeout?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `populated` client event to handle moment when options for depended dropdown loaded from server. Look at the `add_populated` method here http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Client/MicrosoftAjax.Extended/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDownBehavior.pre.js